# Graphics card drivers - dual-link DVI?

Tags: graphics, display

Running default install of Ubuntu 10.04 on PC with Geforce 9500GT graphics card - would there be any problems running a monitor that needs dual-link DVI cables?

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any problems, as long as you have the driver correctly installed by Jockey (Additional Drivers).